# How to find the largest volume of box with dimension limits

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The U.S. Postal Service carries small packages, but when the boxes get big, the post office folks take out a tape measure and measure the length x of the box, the width y of the box, and the height z of the box with all measurements in inches.
If
      x + 2 y + 2 z > 100 ,
then the box is rejected; otherwise it is accepted.
What measurements x , y and z give rise to the acceptable box with the biggest volume?

Comment: I need some help getting started

Comment: You have your constraint equation $x+2y+2z-100 > 0$ and the volume of a box is $V=x \cdot y \cdot z$.

Comment: Hope you're able to solve linear optimization problems...

Comment: I got that far, where do I go after

Comment: Hint: It might also help to set $x+2y+2z=100$ and then solve. After that, substitute into your volume equation (since that is what you want to maximize). Then we can use calculus - partial derivatives - to find potential critical points.

Comment: Hint: due to symetry, $y$ should be equals to $z$

Comment: How can I substitute dimensions in the beginning when the question is asking me to find the dimensions as the final result

Comment: I am writing up an answer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraint equation: $x+2y+2z = 100$, in order to obtain maximum volume. Also $V=x \cdot y \cdot z$. Solving for $x$ we get $x=100-2y-2z$, substitute into our volume equation to obtain $V=(100-2y-2z) \cdot y \cdot z$.

$V_y=100z-4yz-2z^2$

$V_z=100y-2y^2-4yz$.

Now we want to solve $V_y=0$ and $V_z=0$. Hence,

$100z-4yz-2z^2=0$ ... (1)

$100y-2y^2-4yz=0$ ... (2)

From equation (2) we get $y=50-2z$, substituting this into equation (1) we get $z=\frac{50}{3}$ and from the comments, due to symmetry, we get $y=\frac{50}{3}$. We can now solve for $x$ to get $x=\frac{100}{3}$.

Therefore, Length=$\frac{100}{3}$in, Width=$\frac{50}{3}$in, Height=$\frac{50}{3}$in.

Comment: So I don't need to use derivatives?

Comment: @sfewr Yes you do, I used partial derivatives, notation $V_y$, $V_z$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the volume of a box is given by:

$$\mathscr{V}_{\space\text{box}}=\text{L}_{\space\text{box}}\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}\tag1$$

For some number $\text{n}$ it is rejected, and that happends when:

$$\text{L}_{\space\text{box}}+2\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}+2\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}\space>\space\text{n}\tag2$$

Now, what happends when we set it equal to $\text{n}$:

$$\text{L}_{\space\text{box}}+2\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}+2\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}=\text{n}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{L}_{\space\text{box}}=\text{n}-2\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}-2\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}\tag3$$

We get for the volume:

$$\mathscr{V}_{\space\text{box}}=\left(\text{n}-2\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}-2\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}\right)\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}=$$
$$\text{n}\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}-2\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}^2\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}-2\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}^2\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}\tag4$$

Now, we need to solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial\mathscr{V}_{\space\text{box}}}{\partial\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}}=0\\
\\
\frac{\partial\mathscr{V}_{\space\text{box}}}{\partial\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}}=0
\end{cases}\space\space\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\space\begin{cases}\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}\cdot\left(\text{n}-4\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}\right)-2\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}^2=0\\
\\
\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}\cdot\left(\text{n}-2\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}\right)-4\cdot\text{H}_{\space\text{box}}\cdot\text{W}_{\space\text{box}}=0
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a symmetry that can be fruitfully exploited. Replacing $x$ by $2x'$, we have for the dimension constraint $2(x'+y+z)=100$ and $2x'yz$ for the volume of the box. Because of the symmetry of the roles of the three variables, something interesting is bound to happen when $x'=y=z$. Indeed, the AM-GM inequality tells us that the volume of the box is maximized when this occurs. Substituting back into the dimension constraint yields $x=\frac{100}3$ and $y=z=\frac{50}3$.